# Ionic2 root nav

Tags: ionic, ionic2

Galera estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo em *Ionic 2* e na primeira tela *Page1* e executo:

```
this.app.getRootNav().push(Page2)
```

Meu problema é que quando usuário clicar no botão de voltar quero que execute o método `ionViewDidEnter()` da *Page1*.

Ele só executa esse metodo  com `this.nav.push(Page2)` por exemplo.

Queria que funcionasse com `getRootNav`.

Comment: Por favor, [edite](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/246672/edit) sua pergunta e forneça [um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Já tentou usar `ionViewDidLoad`?

Answer (score -1):

Victor, tente com o `ionViewWillEnter`. Para ficar mais claro, o ionViewWillEnter vai ser acionado sempre que você entrar nessa página.

Já o ionViewDidLoad será cacheado e, portanto, disparará as ações apenas uma vez.

Comment: Ja tentei também e não funciona.

Answer (score -2):

getRootNav deprecated

Tenta com o getRootNavId

Caso esteja utilizando Api Http
E no caso do firebase você apenas utiliza o ngOnInit